# Востановление пароля

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Написал вот такой скрипт за 10 минут, но ничего не вышло, не работает. Подскажите, как исправить, чтобы работал.

```
<?php   
    include("../connectdb.php");
          $mobPhone = '+7 903 0827914';
          $email = 'cnofss@ya.ru';

          if (empty($mobPhone)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели номер телефона.";
          } elseif (empty($email)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели E-mail.";
          } // Проверка на ввод
    $usersdb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobPhone='$mobPhone' AND email='$email'");
          $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array(usersdb);

          if (empty($userinfo)) {
            echo "Такого пользователя не существует.";
          } else {
            $updatedbuser = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '2' WHERE `mobPhone` = '$mobPhone' AND `email` = '$email'");
echo "Пароль выслан вам на почту.";
          }

    ?>
```

Comment: @cnofss

    $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array(usersdb);

здесь пропущен знак доллара:

    $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($usersdb);

Comment: Только заметил эту ошибку и вы ответили) Все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика немного нарушена, если проверки удачны, то скрипт все равно выполняется:

```
<?php   
    include("../connectdb.php");
          $mobPhone = '+7 903 0827914';
          $email = 'cnofss@ya.ru';

          if (empty($mobPhone)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели номер телефона.";
          } elseif (empty($email)) {
            echo "Вы не ввели E-mail.";
          } else {
    $usersdb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobPhone='$mobPhone' AND email='$email'");
          $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($usersdb);

          if (empty($userinfo)) {
            echo "Такого пользователя не существует.";
          } else {
            $updatedbuser = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '2' WHERE `mobPhone` = '$mobPhone' AND `email` = '$email'");
echo "Пароль выслан вам на почту.";
          }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Сейчас же исправлю)